# How can i consume a web api writing in php in my xamarin forms project?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie using xamarin forms for mobile app.
The web app is in php and the api too. I dont know how to call my api in my xamarin forms project. I need details please.

Comment: Please read the comment on your previous question about this subject; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185291/xamarins-forms-consume-php-web-api

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HttpClient** for api call in Xamarin.Forms.
Below is example.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri (string.Format (Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));
var response = await client.GetAsync (uri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
{
   var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
   var objectResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <YourObject> (content);
}
```